# Different return when using base64.encodestring with database and session variable

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-views

I'm trying to do API-request and I need API-key to different view. I'm trying to use session variable, but the key seems to be in some other format than trying to use variable from Sqlite database. **API requests work with the key from database, but not with session variable**

How I get API-key from database and from session:

```
key_session = request.session['key']
key_db = APIkey.objects.values_list('key', flat=True).get(pk=2)
```

Both of these return **same values**, when I print them. Key example:

```
3h3asdh-asdasd:oisf87sdf87a5df76asdf83jhjhasgd8
```

I'm using base64.encodestring function when trying to do authentication to API-service with my key:

```
query = request.GET.get('query')
url =  urllib2.Request('https://api.someapiwebsite.com', 
        None, headers={'Content-Type':'application/json'})
base64string = base64.encodestring('%s' % (key_session)).replace('\n', '')
```

If I print base64string with session variable (key_session), I get:

```
MmoihjsdasdoihhaG5tbjpuq9876eq9asd98a7Nmd3dWYzN2JmbWZ2aW1nMGVw==
```

If I print base64string with session variable (key_db), only difference is the two last characters **==** is now **'IC'**, and I think that's why the authentication to API service is failing:

```
MmoihjsdasdoihhaG5tbjpuq9876eq9asd98a7Nmd3dWYzN2JmbWZ2aW1nMGVwIC
```

What is making this difference in the base64 encoded string?

Edit:

I can see difference when using print repr():

```
print repr(key_db)
3h3asdh-asdasd:oisf87sdf87a5df76asdf83jhjhasgd8
print repr(key_session)
3h3asdh-asdasd:oisf87sdf87a5df76asdf83jhjhasgd8\x02\x02
```

Comment: Use `repr`, i.e. `print(repr(key_db)` instead of `print(key_db)`. It might show that one of the strings has trailing whitespace.

Comment: This shows the difference: key_session has \x02\x02 values in the end, but key_db doesn't. How key_session can be different?

Comment: I don't know why `request.session['key']` is different. Maybe it's an issue with your code that sets it. You can strip the characters before encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the strings probably contains some trailing characters that `print` isn't showing. If you use `repr` then you should be able to see what the difference is.

```
print(repr(key_session))
print(repr(key_db))
```

You can then strip any characters as necessary before encoding the string, for example:

```
key_session = key_session.rstrip('\x02')
```